# How to add input field values ( text, date and dropdown ) into a new table or div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I would like to implement something like this in image:

1. It has 3 input fields - Text , Date picker and Dropdown menu .
2. And there are 2 buttons . on click of an "Add row "button ,input field values which we entered should get added to new table/div below .
3. And we should be able to delete the grid when we select it and click " Clear Button"

Can anyone give a solution to this .

[image]

Comment: I tried to do it but couldn't achieve what i wanted . http://codepen.io/vivekhegde99/pen/BWeexY

Comment: your codepen link is not pasted correctly please add again to OP

Comment: Here is the link  http://codepen.io/vivekhegde99/pen/BWeexY

Comment: What is the issue then ?

Comment: @ Tushar,  Instead of adding new row containing input fields , i would like to append all the input field values which i have entered into a new div .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to read data from textbox and then append data to the table :

I have shown the example for one textarea, the same can be done for 2 or more .

```js
  function addRow()
  {
    var name = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    var newHtml = '<tr><td>Name</td><td>'+name+'</td></tr>';
    document.getElementById('table1').innerHTML+=newHtml;
  }
```

```html
Name <input type="text" id="text1" /><br/>
<button onClick="addRow();">Add Row</button>
<hr/>
<table id="table1">
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Test</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Update: For all three fields**

```js
      function addRow()
      {
        var name = document.getElementById('text1').value;
        var date = document.getElementById('date1').value;
        var color = document.getElementById('color1').value;
        var newHtml = '<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+date+'</td><td>'+color+'</td></tr>';
        document.getElementById('table1').innerHTML+=newHtml;
      }
```

```html
<form>
  Name <input type="text" id="text1" /><br/>
    Date <input type="date" id="date1" /><br/>
    Color <select id="color1">
      <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
      <option value="red">red</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button type="reset">Clear</button>
    <br/>
    <button onClick="addRow();">Add Row</button>
    <hr/>
    </form>
    <table id="table1">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Date</td><td>Color</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution , Its working but its getting cleared as soon the "add row" button is clicked. can you please help me out here again.